# What is a watchdog?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm starting with C development and my next job will be to implement a watch dog to control data transfer between threads in C.

What is the meaning of "watch dog", and what does it do?

Comment: its a dog which watches you at work, learns from you and will take over your work if your busy. I am sorry, just google it.

Comment: A Google search will tell you more than we can. In short it's a fail-safe mechanism that's used in case of time-outs

Comment: Maybe your boss wants you to implement and AI that simulates the behaviour of a watch dog, like those from Call of Duty :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A watchdog is a mechanism that periodically tests whether a process or thread is running properly. If it's not, it either restarts it or notifies an administrator, depending on the needs of the application.

The details of how you implement this will depend on the application design.